# Difference between calling named anonymous function and regular subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm experimenting with anonymous functions in Perl, and I began to wonder what the difference between calling these two is:

```
my $read_file = sub {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my @lines;
    
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename or die "Can't open file $filename: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        push @lines, $line;
    }
    close $fh;
    return @lines;
};
```

And this:

```
sub read_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my @lines;
    
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $filename or die "Can't open file $filename: $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        push @lines, $line;
    }
    close $fh;
    return @lines;
}
```

Comment: The calling syntax is different: the first you call `$read_file->($filename)` the second you call like this `read_file($filename)`.

Comment: So there is no difference in terms of speed?

Comment: @Dima: there might be a speed difference in looking them up, but it's neglectable. Your named subroutine declaration is  basically identical to `BEGIN { *read_file = $read_file }` , i.e. the code-ref generated by  `sub {...}` is associated to a symbol `read_file` in the current namespace (aka package).

Comment: ... at compile-time that is. That's what the `BEGIN` does. Of course you have to make sure that `$read_file` is already set then. Or just write `BEGIN { *read_file = sub { ... }  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest, and practically important, difference is that the named subroutine is created at compile time and is in the symbol table (global), while an anonymous one (a code reference) is created at runtime and is local to the scope in which it is created (and can be assigned to a lexical variable).

So a code reference can be created and used within a scope and not be seen outside, like a "local" subroutine<sup>†</sup>, it can be used for a closure, etc.  A named subroutine cannot.

But as for calling them, it's just `subname(ARGS LIST)` vs `$coderef->(ARGS LIST)`.

The phrase used in the question's title, "*named anonymous*" is a misnomer -- it is either named or anonymous (a code reference).

---

<sup>†</sup>
In newer Perls we do have truly local subs, [lexical (private) subroutines](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines)

Answer (score 4):

```perl
sub foo { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```perl
use Sub::Name qw( subname );

BEGIN { *foo = subname foo => sub { ... }; }
```

This illustrates the following differences:

|  | `sub foo { ... }` | `my $foo = sub { ... };` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| compiled | Once, at compile-time. | Once, at compile-time |
| sub's name | Named `foo`. This is returned by `caller`, and it's found in stack traces such as those from `Carp::confess`. | Unnamed, unless `subname` or similar is used as shown above. Leaving it unnamed could lead to frustrating error messages. |
| variable's scope | The sub is assigned to `*foo{CODE}`, which is visible to the entire program (with proper qualification). This permits its exportation. If you want to restrict its scope, you can use [`my sub foo { ... }`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lexical-Subroutines). | The sub is assigned to `my $foo`, which is a lexical variable. It's only visible in the lexical scope in which it is found. Using `our $foo` or a glob would expand that scope if so desired. |
| assignment's timing | The sub is assigned to `*foo{CODE}` when the sub is compiled. This is also when external variables are captured. | The sub is assigned to `$foo` when the assignment is evaluated. This is also when external variables are captured, so each evaluation of the statement creates a new closure. |
| prototype | Calls honour the sub's prototype. | Calling via a reference ignores the sub's prototype. |